# toggleClass Each element One By One jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Problem is that I'm using an array that has more than one element. So, on the toggle, the last class gets passed and functionality given for the last element gets integrated and all starting elements were just added but didn't show any functionality.

I need that each element first to show functionality then toggled to another class.

```
var arrayOfButtonId = [];
$(".buttons-container").click(function (e) {
  var clickedItemId;

  // if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {

  clickedItemId = e.target.id;
  arrayOfButtonId.push(clickedItemId);
  console.log(arrayOfButtonId);
  var counter = 0;
  arrayOfButtonId.forEach((id) => {
    console.log(id, counter++);

    setTimeout(() => {
      $(".sample-display").toggleClass(id,);
    }, 4000);
  });
});
```

For this, In HTML I have Various buttons which can pass the value to js . So that value gets added one by one with some time delay till one function shows its work properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Sample HTML</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <div class="card col-md-6 offset-md-3 shadow text-center animate__animated">
    THis is for Sample.
  </div>

  <div
    class="
      container-fluid
      buttons-container
      col-md-3
      alert-primary
      text-dark
      rounded
    "
  >
    <!-- Animation for Attention Makers -->
    <div class="card col-md-12 my-md-2 py-md-2">
      <span class="text-capitalize font-weight-bold text-center"
        >Attention Maker</span
      >
      <input
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-outline-danger offset-md-1 col-md-10 m-md-3"
        value="Flash"
        id="animate__flash"
      />
      <input
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-outline-danger offset-md-1 col-md-10 m-md-3"
        value="Bounce"
        id="animate__bounce"
      />
      <input
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-outline-danger offset-md-1 col-md-10 m-md-3"
        value="Tada"
        id="animate__tada"
      />
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- script Start-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- script End-->
  <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question to include the relevant HTML so we can create a working example of the issue

Comment: Also include a detailed description of what you expect to happen as it's currently unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.